# Output string and object in a single console.log

Tags: node.js, javascript-objects, console.log

I am using node.js.

`rows` is an object. I want to see the contents of the object.

```
console.log("Contents of rows: ");
console.log(rows);
```

The above code works. Then, I took a short-cut and use

```
console.log("Contents of rows: " + rows);
```

Now, this does not work. Is it possible to have the above work in a single line?

Comment: Use `console.log("Contents of rows: ", rows);`. By concatenating an object, the object is converted into a string.

Comment: Hey! that's the answer! Why don't you put it down as the answer and let me give you points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log("String", objects, arrays);